# How can I handle MySQL disconnection on NodeJS?

Tags: mysql, node.js

First of all, I'm a beginner on NodeJS. Well, I'm using a shared hosting to my project and when the database reaches 1 minute of inactivity, NodeJS crashes and disconnects me from MySQL. Since I'm using a shared hosting, I can't edit the idle time on the MySQL config and I'll need to handle it in code.

I'm using **module.exports** to handle my connection, as shown below. So how can I make an auto-reconnection script to take care of my issue? Thank you.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

module.exports =
{
handle: null,

connect: function(call){
    this.handle = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : '',
        database : 'test',
        timezone: 'utc',
        charset : 'utf8'
    });

    this.handle.connect(function (err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("[MySQL] Connection error: " + err.code);
        } else {
            console.log("[MySQL] Successfully connected");
        }
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Changing the timeout value would only be a workaround, as it does not solve the initial problem. The problem is how you manage and use your db connection. It looks like you create one connection globally reusing it for each DB relevant task, and that is something you should not do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node mysql module that you are using also has a connection pooling mechanism.

Check out the docs at https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections

Connection pools will make you task easier. You can then store the connection pool object and use its `getConnection` method to obtain a connection. Make sure that you release the connection when you are done with it.

If for some reason you cant use connection pooling then you will have to listen for `error` event on the connection and handle it accordingly. But I strongly recommend that you use connection pool.